# Current limit in low-power device

Tags: power, current, current-limiting, fuses

I have a circuit that is powered up by six AA batteries. I am applying for safety certification, and one of the requirements is that the max. current the circuit board can receive is 1.5 A.

I already have a PTC fuse, but that's not acceptable. Are there any other ways I can limit the current without taxing the battery? I looked into a current limiting resistor, but it looks like they will drain some power constantly.

Comment: How about a fuse large enough to let the PTC do its job but small enough to meet code.

Comment: What specific safety certification requirement are you referring to? Is it Atex? If so, what zone etc..

Comment: `limit the current without taxing the battery` ... how would that tax the battery?

Comment: The PTC is not acceptable *to who* and *for what reason*?

Answer (score 1):

> I looked into the current limit resistor, but it looks like they will drain some power constantly.

To limit current you would add a resistor **in series** with your load. This means that it would not drain continuously but would have a power loss proportional to the square of the current through it. \$ P = I^2R \$.

For a 6 V supply and a 1.5 A current limit with a short-circuit the value is calculated by \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 6 {1.5} = 4 \ \Omega \$. This would create a voltage drop of 4 mV/mA drawn by your load. You need to calculate if this is acceptable.